# How to improve while loop insert performance in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, stored-procedures

Here is my SQL Query. It's insert almost 6500+ row from temp table. But its takes 15+ mins! . How can i improve this ? Thanks

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Process_bill]
@userid varchar(10),
@remark nvarchar(500),
@tdate date ,
@pdate date
as

BEGIN 


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo..#temptbl_bill', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temptbl_bill; 

CREATE TABLE #temptbl_bill (
   RowID int IDENTITY(1, 1), 
   ------------

)

// instert into temp table

DECLARE @NumberRecords int, @RowCounter int
DECLARE @batch INT
SET @batch   = 300
SET @NumberRecords = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temptbl_bill)
SET @RowCounter = 1

SET NOCOUNT ON  

BEGIN TRANSACTION

WHILE @RowCounter <= @NumberRecords
BEGIN

declare @clid int
declare @hlid int
declare @holdinNo nvarchar(150)
declare @clientid nvarchar(100)
declare @clientName nvarchar(50)
declare @floor int
declare @radius nvarchar(50)
declare @bill money 
declare @others money
declare @frate int
declare @due money
DECLARE @fine money
DECLARE @rebate money

IF @RowCounter > 0 AND ((@RowCounter % @batch = 0) OR (@RowCounter = @NumberRecords))           
BEGIN                   
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    PRINT CONCAT('Transaction #', CEILING(@RowCounter/ CAST(@batch AS FLOAT)), ' committed (', @RowCounter,' rows)');
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
END;

 // multiple select 


// insert to destination  table

Print 'RowCount -' +cast(@RowCounter as varchar(20))  + 'batch -' + cast(@batch as varchar(20))

SET @RowCounter = @RowCounter + 1;

END

COMMIT TRANSACTION

PRINT CONCAT('Transaction #', CEILING(@RowCounter/ CAST(@batch AS FLOAT)), ' committed (',
@RowCounter,' rows)');

SET NOCOUNT OFF 

DROP TABLE #temptbl_bill

END

GO
```

Comment: Not using a loop in the first place would likely be a start. SQL isn't a programming language it's a Query Language. It excels at set based operations, not iterative ones.

Comment: Have you tried to insert with a single statement `INSERT .. SELECT .. `?

Comment: @Serg sorry, you mean  CTE ?

Comment: take a look at the execution plan to see where the slow part is

Comment: Not necessary CTE. See  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 , example "H. Using the SELECT and EXECUTE options to insert data from other tables"

Comment: Ouch that insert into the temp table makes my eyes bleed. The formatting is just horrific. But it is time to learn about and start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around now for more than 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins But the biggest issue here is looping in the first place. This should be a single insert statement instead of row by agonizing row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As has been said in comments, the loop is completely unnecessary. The way to improve the performance of any loop is to remove it completely. Loops are a last resort in SQL.

As far as I can tell your insert can be written with a single statement:

```
INSERT tbl_bill(clid, hlid, holdingNo,ClientID, ClientName, billno, date_month, unit, others, fine, due, bill, rebate, remark, payment_date, inserted_by, inserted_date) 
SELECT  clid = c.id, 
        hlid = h.id,
        h.holdinNo ,
        c.cliendID, 
        clientName = CAST(c.clientName AS NVARCHAR(50)), 
        BillNo = CONCAT(h.holdinNo, MONTH(@tdate), YEAR(@tdate)),
        date_month = @tDate,
        unit = 0,
        others = CASE WHEN h.hfloor = 0 THEN rs.frate * (h.hfloor - 1) ELSE 0 END, 
        fine = bs.FineRate * b.Due / 100, 
        due  = b.Due, 
        bill = @bill,   -- This is declared but never assigned
        rebate = bs.rebate,
        remark = @remark,
        payment_date = @pdate,
        inserted_by = @userid, 
        inserted_date = GETDATE()
FROM    (   SELECT  id, clientdID, ClientName
            FROM    tbl_client 
            WHERE   status = 1
        ) AS c
        INNER JOIN 
        (   SELECT  id, holdinNo, [floor], connect_radius
            FROM    tx_holding 
            WHERE   status = 1 
            AND     connect_radius <> '0' 
            AND     type = 'Residential'
        ) AS h
            ON c.id = h.clid
        LEFT JOIN tbl_radius_setting AS rs
            ON rs.radius= CONVERT(real,h.connect_radius) 
            AND rs.status = 1 
            AND rs.type = 'Non-Govt.'
        LEFT JOIN tbl_bill_setting AS bs
            ON bs.Status = 1
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  hlid,
                    SUM(netbill) AS Due
            FROM    tbl_bill AS b
            WHERE   date_month < @tdate  
            AND     (b.ispay = 0 OR b.ispay IS NULL) 
            GROUP BY hlid
        ) AS b
            ON b.hlid = h.id
WHERE   NOT EXISTS 
        (   SELECT  1 
            FROM    tbl_bill AS tb 
            WHERE   EOMONTH(@tdate) = EOMONTH(date_month)       
            AND     tb.holdingNo = h.holdinNo
            AND     (tb.update_by IS NOT NULL OR tb.ispay=1)
        );
```

*Please take this with a pinch of salt, it was quite hard work trying to piece together the logic, so it may need some minor tweaks and corrections*

As well as adapting this to work as a single statement, I have made a number of modifications to your existing code:

- Swapped  `NOT IN` for `NOT EXISTS` to avoid any issues with null records. If `holdingNo` is nullable, they are equivalent, if `holdingNo` is nullable, `NOT EXISTS` is safer -  [Not Exists Vs Not IN](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/not-exists-vs-not-in)
- The join syntax you are using was replaced 27 years ago, so I switched from ANSI-89 join syntax to ANSI-92. - [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)
- Changed predicates of `YEAR(date_month) = YEAR(@tDate) AND MONTH(date_month) = MONTH(@tDate)` to become `EOMONTH(@tdate) = EOMONTH(date_month)`. These are syntactically the same, but EOMONTH is [Sargable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean/217983), whereas `MONTH` and `YEAR` are not.

Then a few further links/suggestions that are directly related to changes I have made

- Although I removed the while lopp, don't fall into the trap of thinking this is better than a cursor. A properly declared cursor will out perform a while loop like yours - [Bad Habits to Kick : Thinking a WHILE loop isn't a CURSOR](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/26/bad-habits-to-kick-thinking-a-while-loop-isnt-a-cursor)
- The [general consensus](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/is-adding-the-tbl-prefix-to-table-names-really-a-problem) is that prefixing object names is not a good idea. It should either be obvious from the context if an object is a table/view or function/procedure, or it should be irrelevant - i.e. There is no need to distinguish between a table or a view, and in fact, we may wish to change from one to the other, so having the prefix makes things worse, not better.
- The average ratio of time spent reading code to time spent writing code is around 10:1 - It is therefore worth the effort to format your code when you are writing it so that it is easy to read. This is hugely subjective with SQL, and I would not recommend any particular conventions, but I cannot believe for a second you find your original code free flowing and easy to read. It took me about 10 minutes just unravel the first insert statement.

---

**EDIT**

The above is not correct, `EOMONTH()` is not sargable, so does not perform any better than `YEAR(x) = YEAR(y) AND MONTH(x) = MONTH(y)`, although it is still a bit simpler. If you want a truly sargable predicate you will need to create a start and end date using `@tdate`, so you can use:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', @tdate), '19000101')
```

to get the first day of the month for `@tdate`, then almost the same forumla, but add months to 1st February 1900 rather than 1st January to get the start of the next month:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000201', @tdate), '19000201')
```

So the following:

```
DECLARE @Tdate DATE = '2019-10-11';
SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', @tdate), '19000101'),
        DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000201', @tdate), '19000201');
```

Will return 1st October and 1st November respectively. Putting this back in your original query would give:

```
WHERE   NOT EXISTS 
        (   SELECT  1 
            FROM    tbl_bill AS tb 
            WHERE   date_month >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', @tdate), '19000101'),
            AND     date_month < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000201', @tdate), '19000201')
            AND     tb.holdingNo = h.holdinNo
            AND     (tb.update_by IS NOT NULL OR tb.ispay=1)
        );
```

Comment: Mammoth effort. Wow.

Comment: @GarethD  Thanks a lot. I know this is bad query. I need to study more.This full query is not written by me. Anyway i am checking your code. Again Thanks for your hard work and time .