# Improve INSERT INTO SELECT Query performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I am trying to improve old while loop query. So far tried this but it is still slow. Not sure may be SUM perform slow.

Old query (10 mins+)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[process_tax]
   @userid VARCHAR(10),
   @remark NVARCHAR(500),
   @tdate DATE,
   @roadno NVARCHAR(10),
   @inst INT
AS
BEGIN 
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempProcess_tax_1') IS NOT NULL  
        DROP TABLE #tempProcess_tax_1

    CREATE TABLE #tempProcess_tax_1 
    (
         RowID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), 
         clid_ INT,
         hlid_ INT,
         holdinNo_ NVARCHAR(500),
         holding_ NVARCHAR(50),
         clientid_ NVARCHAR(500),
         clientName_ NVARCHAR(500)
    )

    INSERT INTO #tempProcess_tax_1 (clid_, hlid_, holdinNo_, holding_, clientid_, clientName_)
        SELECT
            cl.clid AS clid_, cl.id AS hlid_, holdinNo, holding,
            ClientID AS clientid_, ClientName AS clientName_  
        FROM
            tx_holding AS cl 
        WHERE
            cl.status = 1 AND cl.roadno = @roadno
            AND cl.id IN (SELECT hlid FROM tx_asset WHERE asset IS NOT NULL) 
            AND cl.clid IN (SELECT id FROM tbl_client WHERE client_type = 'Non-Govt.') 
            AND cl.id NOT IN (SELECT hlid FROM tx_bill_pay 
                              WHERE YEAR(date_month) = YEAR(@tdate) 
                                 AND hlid IS NOT NULL 
                              GROUP BY hlid)

    DECLARE @NumberRecords_1 INT, @RowCounter_1 INT

    SET @NumberRecords_1 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tempProcess_tax_1)
    SET @RowCounter_1 = 1

    WHILE @RowCounter_1 <= @NumberRecords_1
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @clid_ INT
        DECLARE @hlid_ INT
        DECLARE @holdinNo_ NVARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @holding_ NVARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @clientid_ NVARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @clientName_ NVARCHAR(250)
        DECLARE @bill AS MONEY
        DECLARE @sr AS MONEY;

   SELECT  
       @clid_ = clid_,
       @hlid_ = hlid_,
       @holdinNo_ = holdinNo_, @holding_ = holding_,
       @clientid_ = clientid_, @clientName_ = clientName_
   FROM 
       #tempProcess_tax_1 
   WHERE 
       RowID = @RowCounter_1

SET @bill = (SELECT 
                 CASE WHEN SUM(netvalue) IS NULL
                         THEN 0 
                         ELSE SUM(netvalue) 
                 END  
             FROM 
                 tx_bill 
             WHERE 
                 hlid = @hlid_ 
                 AND itemID NOT IN (8, 6) 
                 AND YEAR(date_month) = YEAR(@tdate))
    SET @sr = (SELECT
                   CASE WHEN SUM(asset * rate / 100) IS NULL
                           THEN 0 
                           ELSE SUM(asset * rate / 100) 
                   END
               FROM 
                   tx_bill 
               WHERE
                   hlid = @hlid_ 
                   AND itemID = 6 
                   AND YEAR(date_month) = YEAR(@tdate))

    INSERT INTO tx_bill_pay(clid, hlid, swercharge, pay_bill, pdate, bill_id, holdingNo, holding, ClientID, ClientName, billno, date_month, bill, install, inserted_by, inserted_date) 
    VALUES (@clid_, @hlid_, @sr, @bill / 4, DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(m, 3, @tdate)), CONCAT(@holdinNo_, YEAR(@tdate), '1'), @holdinNo_, @holding_, @clientid_, @clientName_, CONCAT(@holdinNo_, YEAR@tdate)), @tdate, @bill, 1, @userid, GETDATE())

    INSERT INTO tx_bill_pay(clid, hlid, swercharge, pay_bill, pdate, bill_id, holdingNo, holding, ClientID, ClientName, billno, date_month, bill, install, inserted_by, inserted_date) 
    VALUES (@clid_, @hlid_, 0, 2 * (@bill / 4), DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(m, 6, @tdate)), CONCAT(@holdinNo_, YEAR(@tdate), '2'), @holdinNo_, @holding_, @clientid_, @clientName_, CONCAT(@holdinNo_, YEAR(@tdate)), @tdate, @bill, 2, @userid, GETDATE())

    SET @RowCounter_1 = @RowCounter_1 + 1
END

DROP TABLE #tempProcess_tax_1
END
```

New query (1-2 mins)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[process_tax]
   @userid varchar(10),
   @remark nvarchar(500),
   @tdate date ,
   @roadno nvarchar(10),
   @inst int
   as
BEGIN 

 insert  into tx_bill_pay(
          clid,
          hlid,
          swercharge,
          pay_bill,
          pdate,
          bill_id,
          holdingNo,
          holding,
          ClientID, 
          ClientName,
          billno, 
          date_month, 
          bill,
          install ,
          inserted_by, 
          inserted_date)

     select 
           cl.clid,
           cl.id,
     swercharge=(select  case when sum(asset*rate/100) is null then 0 else 
               sum(asset*rate/100) end  from tx_bill where hlid=cl.id and 
               itemID =6 and year(date_month)=YEAR(@tdate)),
     pay_bill=(select  case when sum(netvalue) is null then 0 else 
             sum(netvalue) end  from tx_bill where hlid=cl.id and itemID not 
             in(8,6) and year(date_month)=YEAR(@tdate))/4,  
    DATEADD(day,-1,
    DATEADD(m,3,@tdate)),
    CONCAT(cl.holdinNo, year(@tdate),'1'),
    cl.holdinNo,
    cl.holding,
    cl.ClientID, 
    cl.clientName, 
    CONCAT(cl.holdinNo, 
    year(@tdate)), 
    @tdate,
    bill=(select  case when sum(netvalue) is null then 0 else sum(netvalue) 
         end  from tx_bill where hlid=cl.id and itemID not in(8,6) and 
         year(date_month)=YEAR(@tdate))/4,
    1, 
    @userid, getdate()  
    from  
    (select * 
    from tx_holding as cl 
    where cl.status=1 and cl.roadno=@roadno) AS cl
    INNER JOIN (
     select DISTINCT hlid from tx_asset where asset is not null
     ) AS A 
    ON Cl.id = A.hlid 
     INNER JOIN (
      select DISTINCT  id from tbl_client where client_type='Non-Govt.'
     ) AS C 
    ON   cl.clid=C.id
    WHERE    NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    tx_bill_pay as bp
            WHERE    year(date_month)=year(@tdate)
            and bp.hlid=cl.id
        )   


 insert  into tx_bill_pay(clid,hlid 
    ,swercharge,pay_bill,pdate,bill_id,holdingNo,holding,ClientID, 
    ClientName, billno, date_month, bill, install ,inserted_by, 
    inserted_date)
select 
    cl.clid,
    cl.id,
    0,
    pay_bill=2*((select  case when sum(netvalue) is null then 0 else sum(netvalue) end  from tx_bill where hlid=cl.id and itemID not in(8,6) and year(date_month)=YEAR(@tdate))/4),
    DATEADD(day,-1,
    DATEADD(m,3,@tdate)),
    CONCAT(cl.holdinNo, year(@tdate),'2'),
    cl.holdinNo,
    cl.holding,
    cl.ClientID, 
    cl.clientName, 
    CONCAT(cl.holdinNo, year(@tdate)) , 
    @tdate,
    bill=(select  case when sum(netvalue) is null then 0 else sum(netvalue) 
         end  from tx_bill where hlid=cl.id and itemID not in(8,6) and year(date_month)=YEAR(@tdate))/4,
    2, 
    @userid, getdate()  
from  
    (select * 
    from tx_holding as cl 
    where cl.status=1 and cl.roadno=@roadno) AS cl
    INNER JOIN (
     select DISTINCT hlid from tx_asset where asset is not null
     ) AS A 
    ON Cl.id = A.hlid 
     INNER JOIN (
      select DISTINCT  id from tbl_client where client_type='Non-Govt.'
     ) AS C 
    ON   cl.clid=C.id
    WHERE    cl.id not in
        (   SELECT  hlid
            FROM    tx_bill_pay
            WHERE  year(date_month)=year(@tdate)
            and hlid is not null group by hlid
        )
```

Comment: [Post your query plans](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: Great job getting rid of the loop. But as mentioned nobody can help you here without a LOT more details. Start with the execution plan.

Comment: @DaleBurrell i tried pastetheplan but it show error "The supplied XML did not parse correctly. Are you sure you have a valid query plan XML text?"

Comment: Well....did you paste the xml from the execution plan?

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for your comment and links . It helps me to find out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added non clustered index then my query take 5 sec to run.That's almost solve my problem. @Alex Thanks for your hard work and time. I will check your tips.I Up vote your comment

Answer (score 3):

Great Job removing the loop!

I will point out one possible performance problem, specifically `year(date_month)=year(@tdate)`.

Because a column is wrapped in a function, it is [non-SARGABLE](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-sargable-expressions-in-t-sql-queries-performance-advantages-and-examples/). This means that `date_month` values cannot be evaluated directly and therefore, indexes and statistics for this column cannot be used.

To resolve this I suggest the following changes:

At the top of the SP define two more variables:

```
DECLARE @YearStart AS DATETIME, @NextYearStart DATETIME
SET @YearStart = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, @tdate ), 0 )
SET @NextYearStart = DATEADD( yy, @YearStart, 1 )
```

Then replace all instances of `year(date_month)=year(@tdate)` with

```
@YearStart <= date_month AND date_month < @NextYearStart
```

This above expression looks for `date_month` values greater than or equal to midnight (notice that time component is accounted for) of the first day of the year and less than midnight of the next year.

Next, I would look at the query plan and see if SQL Server gives a ["Missing Index" recommendation](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/07/dude-who-stole-my-missing-index-recommendation/) (it should appear just above the plan diagram, if it does suggest an index). Try adding the recommended missing indexes, then check to see if you get a performance improvement. If you don't get an improvement, remove the index - sometimes suggestions don't help.

### Updated

Having 3 sub-queries (populating columns `swercharge`, `pay_bill`, `bill`) using `tx_bill` table  with different `WHERE` conditions will cause at least 3 evaluations of this table per one main query execution.

It may, depending on the size of the table, be more efficient to calculate all 3 sub-queries once and save results to a temp table (or a table variable) as follows:

```
SELECT hlid,
    ISNULL( SUM( CASE WHEN itemID NOT IN (8, 6) THEN netvalue END ), 0 ) AS Bill,
    ISNULL( SUM( CASE WHEN itemID = 6 THEN asset * rate / 100 END ), 0 ) AS Sr
INTO #Bills
FROM tx_bill 
WHERE @YearStart <= date_month AND date_month < @NextYearStart
    AND NOT hlid IS NULL
GROUP BY hlid
```

In your main queries, join to this table as follows:

```
LEFT JOIN #SumBills AS SumBills ON SumBills.hlid = cl.hlid
```

and in `SELECT` change assignments as per below example:

```
pay_bill= ISNULL( SumBills.Bill, 0 ) / 4,
```

**Note:** I believe you have a bug in `bill` column, as the value is divided by 4, where it is not in the original cursor.

### The last point:

As @GarethD has said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58287197/6305294) to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58286450/how-to-improve-while-loop-insert-performance-in-sql-server), properly formatting your code significantly reduces the time it takes to understand and change the code. I would go one step further and say that code format represents your attitude to and understanding of the problem at hand.

Comment: The non-sargability of this is barely the top of the iceberg imho. There seems to be a lot of room for improvement before even starting to look at indexes.

Comment: @SeanLange, I agree, BUT the above construct crops up in several places in his SP and is 5 min fix. I don't have the time to write up the move `tx_bill` sub queries into a separate query answer :)

Comment: @Alex Thanks for your hard work and time. I will check your tips.I add non clustered index then my query take 5sec to run .